# Why is there a blank white screen rendering?

Tags: rendering, glfw, imgui, glad

I am trying implement GLAD-GLFW-IMGUI version of renderer. I am just trying to display two Imgui windows with docking system. I am using docking branch of Imgui, GLAD(core) and glfw. Below is my code for it. I am getting a blank white window.

```
//HEADERS 

// Emedded font
#include "ImGui/Roboto-Regular.embed"

extern bool g_ApplicationRunning;

static void glfw_error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Glfw Error %d: %s\n", error, description);
}

    void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
    {  glViewport(0, 0, width, height);}

    void Application::Init()
    {
        // Setup GLFW window
        if (!glfwInit())
        {
            std::cerr << "Could not initalize GLFW!\n";
            return;
        }

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

        m_WindowHandle = glfwCreateWindow(m_Specification.Width, m_Specification.Height, m_Specification.Name.c_str(), NULL, NULL);
        if (!m_WindowHandle)
        {
            std::cerr << "Failed to create GLFW window\n";
            glfwTerminate();
            return;
        }



        glfwMakeContextCurrent(m_WindowHandle);
        glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(m_WindowHandle, framebuffer_size_callback);

        if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
        {
            std::cerr << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        // Setup Dear ImGui context
        IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
        ImGui::CreateContext();
        ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO();
        (void)io;
        io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_NavEnableKeyboard;      
        io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_DockingEnable;           // Enable Dockin
        io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_ViewportsEnable;         
        
// Setup Dear ImGui style
        ImGui::StyleColorsDark();


        ImGuiStyle& style = ImGui::GetStyle();
        if (io.ConfigFlags & ImGuiConfigFlags_ViewportsEnable)
        {
            style.WindowRounding = 0.0f;
            style.Colors[ImGuiCol_WindowBg].w = 1.0f;
        }

        // Load default font
        ImFontConfig fontConfig;
        fontConfig.FontDataOwnedByAtlas = false;
        ImFont* robotoFont = io.Fonts->AddFontFromMemoryTTF((void*)g_RobotoRegular, sizeof(g_RobotoRegular), 20.0f, &fontConfig);
        io.FontDefault = robotoFont;



        // Setup ImGui binding
        ImGui_ImplGlfw_InitForOpenGL(m_WindowHandle, true);
        ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Init("#version 410");

    }

    void Application::Shutdown()
    {
        for (auto& layer : m_LayerStack)
            layer->OnDetach();

        m_LayerStack.clear();

        ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Shutdown();
        ImGui_ImplGlfw_Shutdown();
        ImGui::DestroyContext();

        glfwDestroyWindow(m_WindowHandle);
        glfwTerminate();

        g_ApplicationRunning = false;
    }

    void Application::Run()
    {
        m_Running = true;

        ImVec4 clear_color = ImVec4(0.45f, 0.55f, 0.60f, 1.00f);
        ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO();

        // Main loop
        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(m_WindowHandle) && m_Running)
        {

            glfwPollEvents();

            for (auto& layer : m_LayerStack)
                layer->OnUpdate(m_TimeStep);

            // Start the Dear ImGui frame
            ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_NewFrame();
            ImGui_ImplGlfw_NewFrame();
            ImGui::NewFrame();

            {
                static ImGuiDockNodeFlags dockspace_flags = ImGuiDockNodeFlags_None;


                ImGuiWindowFlags window_flags = ImGuiWindowFlags_NoDocking;
                if (m_MenubarCallback)
                    window_flags |= ImGuiWindowFlags_MenuBar;

                const ImGuiViewport* viewport = ImGui::GetMainViewport();
                ImGui::SetNextWindowPos(viewport->WorkPos);
                ImGui::SetNextWindowSize(viewport->WorkSize);
                ImGui::SetNextWindowViewport(viewport->ID);
                ImGui::PushStyleVar(ImGuiStyleVar_WindowRounding, 0.0f);
                ImGui::PushStyleVar(ImGuiStyleVar_WindowBorderSize, 0.0f);
                window_flags |= ImGuiWindowFlags_NoTitleBar | ImGuiWindowFlags_NoCollapse | ImGuiWindowFlags_NoResize | ImGuiWindowFlags_NoMove;
                window_flags |= ImGuiWindowFlags_NoBringToFrontOnFocus | ImGuiWindowFlags_NoNavFocus;

                
                if (dockspace_flags & ImGuiDockNodeFlags_PassthruCentralNode)
                    window_flags |= ImGuiWindowFlags_NoBackground;

                
                ImGui::PushStyleVar(ImGuiStyleVar_WindowPadding, ImVec2(0.0f, 0.0f));
                ImGui::Begin("DockSpace Demo", nullptr, window_flags);
                ImGui::PopStyleVar();

                ImGui::PopStyleVar(2);

                // Submit the DockSpace
                ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO();
                if (io.ConfigFlags & ImGuiConfigFlags_DockingEnable)
                {
                    ImGuiID dockspace_id = ImGui::GetID("GladAppDockspace");
                    ImGui::DockSpace(dockspace_id, ImVec2(0.0f, 0.0f), dockspace_flags);
                }

                if (m_MenubarCallback)
                {
                    if (ImGui::BeginMenuBar())
                    {
                        m_MenubarCallback();
                        ImGui::EndMenuBar();
                    }
                }

                for (auto& layer : m_LayerStack)
                    layer->OnUIRender();

                ImGui::End();
            }

            // Rendering
            ImGui::Render();
            ImDrawData* main_draw_data = ImGui::GetDrawData();
            const bool main_is_minimized = (main_draw_data->DisplaySize.x <= 0.0f || main_draw_data->DisplaySize.y <= 0.0f);

            if (!main_is_minimized)
                ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_RenderDrawData(main_draw_data);

            // Update and Render additional Platform Windows
            if (io.ConfigFlags & ImGuiConfigFlags_ViewportsEnable)
            {
                GLFWwindow* backup_current_context = glfwGetCurrentContext();
                ImGui::UpdatePlatformWindows();
                ImGui::RenderPlatformWindowsDefault();
                glfwMakeContextCurrent(backup_current_context);
            }

            float time = GetTime();
            m_FrameTime = time - m_LastFrameTime;
            m_TimeStep = glm::min<float>(m_FrameTime, 0.0333f);
            m_LastFrameTime = time;
        }

    }

    void Application::Close()
    {
        m_Running = false;
    }

    float Application::GetTime()
    {
        return (float)glfwGetTime();
    }
```

I think there is a problem with my glfw implementation. I cant figure out. How can i display the output? What should be corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not swapping your buffers.

```
Add  glfwSwapBuffers(m_WindowHandle); to the end of your run function.
```

There are two buffers - one currently shown and one you draw on.

This function swaps the front and back buffers of the specified window